# Symmetrical, self-referential HABTM relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-and-belongs-to-many

In my schema I have a model called Imprintables. In this model I have this self-referential relationship:

```
class Imprintable < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :coordinates, class_name: 'Imprintable', association_foreign_key: 'coordinate_id', join_table: 'coordinates_imprintables'
...
end
```

In the imprintable create/edit form I have a select field where users can select coordinate imprintables (coordinates are used to identify imprintables that are similar to the one being created/edited). My issue is that if I have an imprintable A and and imprintable B, when I create A and list B as a coordinate imprintable, I want to be able to look at the edit form for B and see A also listed as a coordinate.

I've tried modifying the controller's update and create action to insert both pairs of id's into the linker table (coordinates_imprintables). For instance if A.id = 1 and B.id = 2, then executing some sql like:

```
INSERT INTO coordinates_imprintables (imprintable_id, coordinate_id) VALUES (1, 2)
INSERT INTO coordinates_imprintables (imprintable_id, coordinate_id) VALUES (2, 1)
```

But I couldn't get it working because I'm not sure how to know when a user is trying to delete or insert a coordinate, and I'm not even sure if that's the correct answer anyway. Railscasts have been marginally helpful, this just seems like a tricky case because I have a model with a self-referential relationship that is also symmetrical. Thanks for you time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you seem to be looking for here are [model callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html). These execute before, after, or during actions in an object's lifecycle.

In order to use these for your situation, you can add a model for your `CoordinatedImprintable` table. Then, whenever you create, update, or destroy a `coordinate_imprintable`, you'll need to do the same thing for its mirror.

```
class CoordinateImprintable < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imprintable
  belongs_to :coordinate, class_name: 'Imprintable', foreign_key 'imprintable_id'
  after_create :add_mirror
  after_update :update_mirror
  after_destroy :destroy_mirror

  def add_mirror
    self.class.find_or_create(imprintable: coordinate, coordinate: imprintable)
  end

  def update_mirror
    if self.changed?
      mirror = self.class.find(imprintable: coordinate_was, coordinate: imprintable_was)
      mirror.update_attributes(imprintable: coordinate, coordinate: imprintable)
    end
  end

  def destroy_mirror
    mirror = self.class.find(imprintable: coordinate, coordinate: imprintable)
    mirror.destroy if mirror && !mirror.destroyed
  end
end
```

You'll also need change your `has_and_belongs_to_many` relation to two `has_many :through` relations.

```
class Imprintable
  has_many :coordinate_imprintables
  has_many :coordinate, through: :coordinate_imprintables
  has_many :mirrored_coordinate_imprintables, class_name: 'CoordinateImprintable', foreign_key: 'coordinate_id'
  has_many :mirrored_coordinates, through: :mirrored_coordinate_imprintables, source: :imprintable
end
```

Hopefully this helps! And feel free to comment with any questions.

Comment: This would require me to not use a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship though, right? Since HABTM only uses a join table with no related model? Currently I don't have a CoordinateImprintable model.

Comment: Yes, you'd have to make the change, but it shouldn't be too difficult. I've added that to my answer.

Comment: Alrighty took me a little while and a few pulled hairs but I finally got it working! Thanks for your help

Comment: No problem! I'm glad to be of service!