# has_and_belongs_to_many self join only associates one way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a User model, that I want to connect to itself through a self join using has_and_belongs_to_many. I have it working almost as expected, except I want it to associate the two users both ways.

My User class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_and_belongs_to_many :friends,
      autosave: true,
      class_name: 'User',
      join_table: :friendships,
      foreign_key: :user_id,
      association_foreign_key: :friend_user_id
  ...
end
```

My migration:

```
class CreateFriendships < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :friendships, id: false do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :friend_user_id
    end

    add_index(:friendships, [:user_id, :friend_user_id], :unique => true)
    add_index(:friendships, [:friend_user_id, :user_id], :unique => true)
  end

  def self.down
    remove_index(:friendships, [:friend_user_id, :user_id])
    remove_index(:friendships, [:user_id, :friend_user_id])
    drop_table :friendships
  end
end
```

My problem:

```
user1 = User.find(1)
user2 = User.find(2)

user1.friends << user2
user1.reload.friends.exists?(user2) # true
user2.reload.friends.exists?(user1) # false <- My problem
```

How can I make the relationship work both ways? As friendships are always mutual in this context and other questions on SO make it seem as this should be possible, I would like for both the last two statements to return true.

Comment: You can also check out [the solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24310533/symmetrical-self-referential-habtm-relationship/24311078#24311078) I posted for a similar question on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The less hackish approach is to build friendships inside of your own method:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def make_friend(user)
    # TODO: put in check that association does not exist
    self.friends << user
    user.friends << self
  end
end
```

And to call it like

```
user1.make_friend(user2)
# should set both friends know about each other
```

The more hackish one is to trick with `ActiveRecord::Associations` methods overriding. E.g. `has_and_belongs_to_many's` method `collection<<(object, …)` can be revised for your case with something like that:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :reversed  # we use it to avoid stack level too deep issue
  has_and_belongs_to_many :friends, ... do
    def << (new_friend)
      reversed = true
      # it should not trigger on our friend record as self.reversed is true
      new_friend.friends << self unless new_friend.reversed
      super new_friend
    end     
  end
end
```

**NOTE**: I'm not sure about `self` meaning inside of `<<` method, so may be you should dig the real object instance somehow through relation object.

Comment: You came up with pretty much the same solution, that I did in the meantime, so I will probably just use that.
`def add_friend(user)
    self.friends << user unless self.friends.exists?(user)
    user.friends << self unless user.friends.exists?(self)
end`

Answer (score 0):

You can also do...

```
user2.friends << user1
```

It does mean there are two join records.

Comment: I realize this is possible, but it doesn't really make it bidirectional, as I was hoping.

Comment: I can't remember if Ryan Bates addressed this but check out http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association