# Has and belongs to many call in both ways

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I have two tables students and teachers like:

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :students
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :teachers
end
```

If I create a student like

```
teacher.students.create(...)
```

I will be able to call 
`teacher.students.last`
but not `student.teachers.last`

Am I using the wrong association?

Comment: Please show some complete code that reproduces the problem. Did you save the student?

Comment: I am trying in rails console. I am just running Teacher.last.students.create()

Comment: And you're assigning that created object where? What do you do with the object after? You can paste your console commands just as easily.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Symmetrical, self-referential HABTM relationship](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24310533/symmetrical-self-referential-habtm-relationship)

Comment: `Teacher.last.students.create()` then `Teacher.last.students` returns the good student but `Student.last.teachers.last` returns nil